# ASP.NET MVC - Code analysis / auditing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, code-analysis

I believe it would be useful to be able to produce an informal report quantifying several aspects of my ASP.NET MVC project.  The intent is to help me determine where I should be focusing my efforts for testing/refactoring.

Some metrics that might be useful to a developer...

- List action methods and the number of unit tests for each
- List action methods and the number of lines of code for each
- List action methods that do not use the Authorize attribute

I can produce a list of controllers/methods using reflection.

```
var controllers = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
  .Where(t => typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom(t)).ToList();

foreach (var controller in controllers)
{    
  var methods = controller.GetMethods()
    .Where(m => m.IsAControllerNotDefinedHere()).ToList();

  foreach (var method in methods)
    // do something
}
```

Unfortunately, I fear that if I continue I might end up dumping alot of time into this and end up with something that is difficult to maintain/reuse.

Does anyone have any suggestions for existing solutions (code snippets, open-source, or commercial) that can help me accomplish this goal?

**UPDATE:** 
I'm still seeking input hoping that there is an affordable (or free) solution out there, but I thought I would share some useful reflection techniques that can be used for this purpose.

**GetCustomAttributes**

```
var controllers = ...;
var controllersWithAuthorizeAttribute = controllers
  .Where(c => c.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute), false).Count() > 0).ToList();

var methods = ...;
var methodsWithHttpPostAttribute = methods
  .Where(m => m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.Web.Mvc.HttpPostAttribute), false).Count() > 0).ToList();
```

**Unit Test Count**

```
// get all types in your unit test project
var types = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(A.UnitTest.Class)).GetTypes();
// get the test class specific to the current controller (arbitrary)
var testClass = types.Where(t => t.Name == controller.Name + "Tests").SingleOrDefault();
// get unit tests from that test class (specific to NUnit)
var unitTests = testClass.GetMethods().Where(m => m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(NUnit.Framework.TestAttribute), false).Count() > 0);
// count tests (relying on consistent naming scheme - again arbitrary)
var num = unitTests.Where(t => t.Name.StartsWith(...).Count();
```

**Amount of Code**

I couldn't count lines of code using reflection, but I was able to determine the number of Intermediate Language bytes which allows me to give greater scrutiny to those methods that have a higher number of IL bytes.

```
var method = ...;
var numBytes = method.GetMethodBody().GetILAsByteArray().Length;
```

All in all, not even close to perfect.  However, I can get the data I need repeatedly without convincing someone to spend money on a commercial product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few standard OTS products (some may be free) that do what you are saying. Here are a few that I have used:

1. NCover - Provides test coverage. The metrics this provides are good for illuminating areas where testing should be beefed up. I by no means recommend 100% test coverage...but the percentage should be high.
2. NDepend - Provide code analysis / metrics that illuminate classes that may need to be refactored.
3. ReSharper - Code analysis as you type to provide a 'coding standard' that all developers follow. This is an extremely helpful tool to ensure everyone's code meets a common standard. Very nice.

Bob